# rails wont install on my mac, filepath error? gems error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I cant install rails with the usual commannd it gets ignored on my mac. However it seems to be installed according to the terminal output.

[image]

Comment: seems to work without sudo, dont understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found by typing

```
sudo gem environment
```

then

```
gem environment
```

and comparing the results. (**gem env** is a short version of the command)

Ruby gems are installed locally in directory under specific ruby version, which is also installed in user specific folder (not sure bout MAC situation, but that's the case on my Ubuntu).

Please see the difference on my machine (I am using rvm - ruby version manager):

```
with sudo - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0

without sudo - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/le-hu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2
```

Using sudo in this case causes the gem to install under root user, not your regular user profile, this leads into gem missing while trying to invoke the gem script being logged in as not-root user.

Comment: thanks, how do i fix the issue and stop sudo pointing to the wrong ruby? when i come to run "bundle install" it says i am running the wrong version of ruby: USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/marc/.gem/ruby/2.6.0

Comment: please try to install rails by "gem install rails" without sudo, then try bundle install - also without sudo